# Cant retrieve document from firestore after move function to another activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the following function, I am retrieving the user information (username and bio) from firebase cloud database. However, the log says that there is no such document, which means that the document does not exist. In the main activity, the document was uploaded successfully to the database. Could this be that the retrieve user info function executed before the document was uploaded?
Thanks in advance!

The following code is from SignupActivity:

```
 private void retrieveProfileViaURLandUploadUserInfo (final String user, final String bioInfo) {
        profileRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                pathToProfile = uri.toString();
                String UID = getUserID();
                UserInfo.put(USERNAME, user);
                UserInfo.put(BIO, bioInfo);
                UserInfo.put(PROFILE_URL, pathToProfile);
                Log.d(TAG, "Got UID");
                mDocRef.collection("users").document(UID).set(UserInfo)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Log.d(USER_INFO, "Document has been saved");
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.w(USER_INFO, "Document was not saved!", e);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.d(TAG, "retrieve profile image failure");
                // pathToProfile = "uri download unsuccessful";
            }
        });
    }
```

This is in HomeActivity

```
public void retrieveDisplayUserInfo() {
        String UID = getUserID();
        Log.d(TAG, UID);
        mDocRef.collection("users").document(UID).get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();

                            if (document.exists()) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                                String userName = document.getString(USERNAME);
                                String shortBio = document.getString(BIO);
                                String URL = document.getString(PROFILE_URL);

                                displayUserName = findViewById(R.id.usernameView);
                                displayUserName.setText(userName);
                                displayBio = findViewById(R.id.shortBio);
                                displayBio.setText(shortBio);
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Here are the StackTrace

```
D/EmailPassword: createAccount:dfajlkj@fadf.com
I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@9ba0059
I/m.test.testaut: IncrementDisableThreadFlip blocked for 7.062ms
W/m.test.testaut: Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (light greylist, reflection)
W/m.test.testaut: Accessing hidden field Ljava/net/Socket;->impl:Ljava/net/SocketImpl; (light greylist, reflection)
W/m.test.testaut: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, linking)
W/m.test.testaut: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, linking)
W/m.test.testaut: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, linking)
W/m.test.testaut: Accessing hidden field Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;->descriptor:I (light greylist, JNI)
W/m.test.testaut: Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
W/m.test.testaut: Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
W/m.test.testaut: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (light greylist, linking)
W/m.test.testaut: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( zx03kHuJ6Rh1ecQexeWMmwSHHZS2 ).
D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying auth state listeners about user ( zx03kHuJ6Rh1ecQexeWMmwSHHZS2 ).
D/UploadTask: Increasing chunk size to 524288
D/EmailPassword: createUserWithEmail:success
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 11221
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@e040231
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 254213927
V/FA: onActivityCreated
W/m.test.testaut: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromAssetManager(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;IZIII[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromBuffer(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;II)Z (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->freeze()Z (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->abortCreation()V (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->createFromFamiliesWithDefault([Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;Ljava/lang/String;II)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; (light greylist, reflection)
D/EmailPassword: zx03kHuJ6Rh1ecQexeWMmwSHHZS2
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 254214029
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8e40a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe8e4c590)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8e40a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe8e4c590)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8e40a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe8e4c590)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8e40a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe8e4c590)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8e40a20: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe8e4c590)
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
    Connection attempt already in progress
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
D/EmailPassword: No such document
D/EmailPassword: upload profile image successful
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: Where are you adding the user to your database? If you look at the "users" collection in Firestore, does the user actually exist? Is the document ID = to the UID? It's difficult to tell what's happening without knowing where the retrieveDisplayUserInfo function is located relative to the rest of your application.

Comment: Without seeing the code that also writes the document, it's not possible to say why it's not found from the query shown here.

Comment: Sorry guys, I have added the code that writes the document